# Help me find a book describing two specific walks across Paris, France

Tags: france, paris, walking, guidebooks

I once had a small book (in French) that covered two approx. half-day walks across Paris, France.

- One went north-to-south: it perhaps started at a science museum up north and ended at a university campus down south.
- The other went east to west: it perhaps started and ended at two of the large parks in the east and west of town respectively.

I did them both (more than a decade ago), but can no longer remember the book's title. The book was specifically on this topic and it may have been from a (semi-)official source, such as a French national geographic society.

Can anybody tell its title or point me to other information (perhaps even an app, nowadays) about those two walks?

Comment: Possible candidates : science museum up north -> Cité des sciences (Parc de La Villette), campus down south -> Cité Universitaire, east park -> Bois de Vincennes, west park -> Bois de Boulogne

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I have now found what I was looking for. The then book was [*Topo-guide des sentiers de randonnée : GR de pays, Paris à pied*](https://www.amazon.fr/Topo-guide-sentiers-randonn%C3%A9e-pays-Paris/dp/2856996310) published by [FFRandonnée](https://www.ffrandonnee.fr/) (*Fédération Française de la Randonnée Pédestre*) in 1997.

[This](https://www.gr-infos.com/grp-paris1.htm) [site](https://www.gr-infos.com/grp-paris.htm) apparently refers to the same two walks (and also shows maps):

- north-south: from Porte de la Villette to Porte d'Arcueil (Parc Montsouris)
- east-weat: from Porte Dauphine (Bois de Boulogne) to Porte Dorée (Bois de Vincennes)

A newer guide, [*Paris ... à pied*](https://boutique.ffrandonnee.fr/topoguide-paris-a-pied) from 2016, contains descriptions of three walks with the following summaries (translation courtesy of Google Translate). It might be a newer version of the same book with routes no. 2 and 3 being those I was looking for.

> Traversée N ° 1 is west-east oriented. It crosses the Seine twice but
>   is largely left bank. The route travels through picturesque
>   neighborhoods, such as the Latin Quarter and the Montagne Ste
>   Geneviève, evoking the Philippe-Auguste enclosure, and the lower
>   Bièvre. The circuit also allows to take several large green areas:
>   Champs de Mars, Luxembourg garden, Jardin des Plantes or the park of
>   Bercy.
>
> Traversée N ° 2 is a North-South route, with more pronounced relief,
>   which connects two major Haussmann parks: the parks of Buttes-Chaumont
>   and Montsouris. It allows to survey some historic districts such as
>   the Marais and its mansions, the medieval streets of the
>   Maubert-Saint-Séverin sector or the Mouffetard district.
>
> Traversée N ° 3 is oriented West-East, connecting Porte Maillot to the
>   Porte Dorée, and offers you a discovery of the old villages of the
>   capital. The Musarde route through Parc Monceau or Belleville,
>   exploring the Buttes-Chaumont Park, climbing the Montmartre hill and
>   the Belleville plateau, or along the old Petite Ceinture railway.

Comment: That whole series is really good - the directions to and on the paths are good, the sights are nicely described, the difficulty is accurate..  They cover pretty much all of France, and I'd recommend for any hiker